# Setting bean properties from a thread

Tags: multithreading, jsf, primefaces

I have a `@ViewScoped` bean that passes itself to a Thread object.

```
class SomeThread implements Runnable {
  private SomeBeanClass someBean;
  public SomeThread(SomeBeanClass someBean) {
    this.someBean = someBean;
  }

  public void run() {
    // do some calculations and set bean properties    
    someBean.setProperty("blabla");
    someBean.setLocked(false);
  }
```

This seems to work most of the times, but not very stable. In my view, I use PrimeFaces' `p:poll` to refresh a `h:inputTextarea` which displays the property I set in the thread. It works... sometimes. Sometimes I see no text at all, sometimes it only displays new text for the first poll.

The boolean property I set in the thread doesn't seem to be up to date if I call an action method from my form while the thread is running (the thread set it to `false`, after that I invoke the action method from the form and `isLocked()` still returns `true`).

Is there any more clever way to do this? Passing a bean to a thread seems wrong to me. But how else could I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

My goal is as follows: I want the user to be able to see changes made to some files that lie on a remote server (without refreshing). Basically, I want the user to see a `tail -f` of a remote file in an `inputTextarea`. (The connection to the remote server is done by the thread using SSH [Ganymed library]).

So I put the `inputTextarea` in the form and refresh it using `p:poll`. I update the String that is bound to the `inputTextarea` in the thread (the user invokes the action that will start the thread using a `commandButton`. Also, I want the user to stop the `tail -f` via a `selectBooleanCheckbox`. So I put a condition in the `run()` method of the thread:

```
if(someBean.isFinished()) {
  // logout and break;
}
```

The changes made to the `selectBooleanCheckbox` are reflected in the run method straight away because I used `<f:ajax />` - but bean properties set from the run method are sometimes not "updated" right away.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.12, JSF 2 (MyFaces) and PrimeFaces 2.2.1

Comment: This is absolutely not the way how to go about it. Before giving an answer, please mention the functional requirement in detail, along with the exact servletcontainer make/version.

Comment: I updated the description. I hope it's a bit clearer now. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ah Tomcat, so use of EJB and a container managed scheduler is totally out of question. Interesting functional requirement though.

Answer (score 3):

Managed beans in JSF are inherently volatile so this approach is completely wrong.

The Primefaces `<p:poll>` object handles routine refreshes for you that you will be able to post back on a repeated interval to get the next set of results.

Here is the following code sample that is available on the Primefaces demo page of how this component should be used.

```
<h:form>

    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Start"
            image="ui-icon-play" onclick="poll.start()" />
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Stop"
            image="ui-icon-pause" onclick="poll.stop()" />

    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />

    <p:poll interval="4" listener="#{counterBean.increment}"
            update="txt_count" widgetVar="poll" autoStart="false"/>

</h:form>
```

Here is a link to view how the Primefaces demo should work: [Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf)

What you should do is on each call to the `listener` method of your managed bean, check for the latest updates on your filesystem and then update the contents of your managed bean.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the listener method! What I don't understand: I can't just "check for the latest updates" because the tail -f (it really is a tail -f) is running all the time. I need to update some attribute from that thread. Or how else could I achieve it? I never return from the thread until it's completely finished. Everything else would be difficult.

Comment: The problem with this thread is that if it begins modifying properties of the managed bean then it will potentially maintain a lock on the object.  The thread should update the properties of some volatile object, and the `listener` method of the bean should check the volatile object for the latest information.  The thread however is running outside of the bean.

Comment: Yes, if you pass an object to a thread, all references to that object will still be able to access this object.  And Yes, your managed bean will have access to this object, as well as the thread.  If you are still confused then you should refresh the basic concepts of multi-threaded programming in Java.